# $x_n =\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{i!}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

From *Topology Without Tears*:

Show that $x_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{i!}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$

First thing, I believe being convergent in $\mathbb{Q}$, means sequence and  the converging point must also belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. What does it mean sequence is Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}$?Does it just mean sequence is entirely in $\mathbb{Q}?$

I was trying to show Cauchy:
let $n>m$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|x_n-x_m|&=|\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{i!}-\sum_{i=0}^{m}\frac{1}{i!}|\\
&=|\sum_{i=m+1}^{n}\frac{1}{i!}|\\
&=|\frac{1}{m+1!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}|\\
& \leq \frac{1}{m+1!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}\\
&<\frac{1}{m}+...\frac{1}{n} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since the number of terms are $n-m $.I was thinking to take each term $<\frac{\epsilon}{n-m}$, to get $n_0\in \mathbb{N},\ such\ that\ |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon,\forall n,m>n_0$.

But I think this will be wrong and looks odd,saying choosing $m>\frac{\epsilon}{n-m}$

How should I show this is Cauchy?

Comment: You mean Cauchy sequence(s), not caushy.  The estimate $\frac{1}{k!}<\frac1k$ is too rough (the harmonic series diverges).

Comment: A sequence being Cauchy intuitively means it "ought" to converge if you look at how the distance between the terms shrink as you go further and further out in the sequence, but without the requirement that an actual limit exists in your space.

Answer (score 4):

$(m+1)!$ is a product of $m+1$ numbers all except one of which is $2$ or more. So $(m+1)!\geq 2^{m}$. Similarly,  $(m+2)!\geq 2^{m+1}$ and so on. So $\frac 1 {m+1}!+..+\frac 1 {n!} \leq \frac 1 {2^{m}}+\frac  1 {2^{m+1}}+...$. Can you write down this geometric sum and show that it is less than $\epsilon$ if $m$ is large enough?

Comment: can you solve it further I am finding it difficult to solve and find the required  $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The value of the geometric sum is $ \frac 1 {2^{m-1}}$. When is this less than  $\epsilon$? @mathstudent

Comment: This is less than $\epsilon $ when $\frac{1}{\epsilon }<2^{m-1}$ or  $\frac{2}{\epsilon}<2^m $ I am unable to simplify further..

Comment: @mathstudent Take logarithm and divide both sides by $\ln 2$.

Comment: But can we divide by log 2?Because left side  $\log (\frac{2}{\epsilon})=\log 2 - \log \epsilon$.I used this and got $m>1-\frac{log \epsilon}{log 2}$ Am I correct?

Comment: Am I doing wrong,please reply?

Comment: @mathstudent $m >1-\frac {log \epsilon} {log 2}$ is correct.